# How to change string "One Two Three<5 spaces>.zip" to "One Two Three.zip"

Tags: powershell

I have a file name string which contains several trailing spaces before the extension:

```
One Two Three     .Zip
```

I want to preserve the spaces *between* the words, but remove any extra spaces after the word "Three", but before the ".Zip".  Using PowerShell, how can I change that string into:

```
One Two Three.Zip
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses FileInfo to grab the BaseName for the file (i.e file name without extension), then TrimEnd to remove spaces on the end of the BaseName, and then appends the Extension back on.

PowerShell has a Get-Item command that will get the FileInfo instance for you but it expects the file to exist.  If necessary, you can use System.IO.FileInfo directly.

```
$inputFileName = "One Two Three     .zip" 

# If you know the file exists, you can use the Get-Item command.
$fileInfo = Get-Item $inputFileName
$outputFileName = $fileInfo.BaseName.TrimEnd() + $fileInfo.Extension
Write-Host $outputFileName

# Or if the file doesn't exist, you can drop down to the .NET FileInfo class.
$fileInfo = [System.IO.FileInfo]$inputFileName
$outputFileName = $fileInfo.BaseName.TrimEnd() + $fileInfo.Extension
Write-Host $outputFileName
```

Comment: Thanks David this looks good although I haven't tested it yet - my hands are full with the Xmas turkey :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
("One Two Three     .zip".Split('.') | % {$_.trim()}) -join '.'
```

The thing you haveto uderrtand is that in Poweshell everything is object. First I apply the method `Split` on the string. This method generate an array of two substrings, then for each one (`%`) I apply the method `Trim`, then I join both of the array elements by a `'.'`.

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc that works fine - just trying to understand what is happening - on the left side of the pipe it seems strings left and right of the "." are returned - then I am curious - do both these string get passed through the pipe - so the $ holds each of the strings and then trims them in the for each loop (%) - and then joins them ?